# Specify tar for GitHub release

Tags: github, github-api

What specific syntax must be used in order to specify that a particular `tar` file must be published as a GitHub release starting from the code below?

The source code for the app is being compiled into a binary with generated dependencies, which are then compressed into a `tar` file named `myapp_vX.X.X.tar`.  We need to make sure that the `myapp_vX.X.X.tar` file is what is published as the release.

We found the following command [at this link](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases#create-a-release), but you can see that this command does not specify which file to publish as the release.

```bash
gh api \
  --method POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  /repos/MyAccount/MyRepo/releases \
  -f tag_name='$VERSION' \
  -f target_commitish='master' \
  -f name='$VERSION' \
  -f body='$DESCRIPTION' \
  -F draft=false \
  -F prerelease=false \
  -F generate_release_notes=false
```

What needs to be changed in order to specify that the `myapp_vX.X.X.tar` file will be what gets published as the release?

Comment: Where _is_ that tar file? If you're trying to add an extra asset to the release, surely you want https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/assets#upload-a-release-asset. You should probably start with the basics of what a release actually is in GitHub: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/about-releases.