# Windows command line variable in Git command

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

What specific syntax needs to be changed in the windows command line commands below in order for `git remote add origin %repoWithToken%` to resolve to the intended valid URL?

**COMMANDS THAT ARE FAILING:**

The following commands are run in a `pwsh` shell on a `windows-latest` GitHub runner.

```
set repoWithToken="https://"$GIT_PAT"@github.com/accountName/repoName.git"
git init
git remote add origin %repoWithToken%
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

The following error message is given by the GitHub windows-latest runner when the above code is run:

```
fatal: '%repoWithToken%' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The answer can just be simple windows command line command.  No need for any fancy PowerShell.

Also, `$GIT_PAT` is correct GitHub syntax, though it is possible that the concatenation in `set repoWithToken="https://"$GIT_PAT"@github.com/accountName/repoName.git"` might need to be done differently in the code above.  This is in the process of being translated from Bash.

Comment: In PowerShell `set` is an alias for `Set-Variable`. Is there a special reason why you're not using the native PowerShell cmdlets? If you want to use a variable in PowerShell it will not work with `%repoWithToken%`. You have to use `$repoWithToken`. And you can create the variable like this: `$repoWithToken = "https://$($GIT_PAT)@github.com/accountName/repoName.git"`

Comment: @Olaf The reason is I just want to keep it simple.  I am a bash and python person who occasionally needs to write a simple windows script.  If you have a simple solution about which you feel conviction, I would be happy to see it.

Comment: Since you seem familiar with CMD the simplest solution would be to use CMD instead of PowerShell.

Comment: @Olaf There are a couple other powershell commands upstream in the same script, so that making these lines become powershell lines is an option.  Separately, a windows command prompt version would need to do the concatenation correctly.  The above concatenation of the `$GIT_PAT` variable works in bash, but `$GIT_PAT` is a GitHub variable, so I am not sure if `%$GIT_PAT%` would work.

Comment: I'm not sure if I really get it. If you want to use `$GIT_PAT` literally you can assign the variable in PowerShell like this: `$repoWithToken = 'https://$GIT_PAT@github.com/accountName/repoName.git'` ( enclosed in single quotes ). And you can use it like this: `git remote add origin $repoWithToken`

Comment: **Editor's note**: please don't use quote blocks in your questions unless they are in someone else's voice. This is appearing in too many of your questions, and reduces their readability. (Your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73640247/specify-tar-for-github-release) was locked relating to this reason).

Comment: @Olaf The syntax is actually more like `$repoWithToken = 'https://$env:GIT_PAT@github.com/accountName/repoName.git'` .  If you want to write that up with your comments as an answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted and +1.

Comment: @CodeMed That will not work since variables will not be expanded inside single quotes. ;-) What about MKlement0's answer? I couldn't explain it better.

Comment: @CodeMed: you are mistaken. After a certain level of rep, there is no rep to be garnered. I have long gone past the point of getting rep for edits - I think that level is 3k.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf)'s helpful comments:

- `set <varName>=<value` is used *in `cmd.exe`* for assigning variables; while in PowerShell `set` is a built-in *alias* for [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable), the latter has very *different syntax*.

  - More importantly, its use is rarely needed, because variables are assigned as `$<varName> = <value>`
  - PowerShell uses the same syntax on *setting* and *getting* variable values, `$<varName>`; thus, after having assigned to a variable named `repoWithToken` with `$repoWithToken = <value>`, you also refer to its *value* later with `$repoWithToken` (by contrast, `%repoWithToken%` is again *`cmd.exe`* syntax).
- Assuming that `GIT_PAT` is the name of an *environment* variable, you must refer to it as `$env:GIT_PAT` in PowerShell variable (with explicit name delineation: `${env:GIT_PAT}`)
- Unlike Bash (and POSIX-compatible shells in general), PowerShell only allows you to compose a single string from a mix of quoted and unquoted tokens if the *first* token is unquoted.

  - Something like `"https://"$GIT_PAT"@github.com/accountName/repoName.git"` therefore doesn't work as a *single* string argument, because its first token is *quoted*, causing PowerShell to break it into *two* arguments in this case.
  - Since string interpolation is needed here in order to replace `${env:GIT_PAT}` with its value, simply enclose the *entire* value in `"..."`, i.e. make it an [expandable string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)

Therefore:

```
$repoWithToken = "https://${env:GIT_PAT}@github.com/accountName/repoName.git"
git init
git remote add origin $repoWithToken
```